# Haproxy redirect rule path elements variable not working

Tags: redirect, nginx, haproxy

I have the following redirect rule in nginx

```
rewrite ^/rty/(.*)$ example.com/$1?lead
```

I am trying to do same in haproxy

```
acl uri_lc path_reg ^/lc/(.*)$
http-request redirect location example.com/$1?lead  code 301 if uri_lc
```

The redirect working but the path element variable $1 seems not work with haproxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite request using the [`http-request's`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4.2-http-request) `set-path` and `set-query`.

```
# remove /rty part
http-request set-path %[path,regsub(/rty,,g)] 

# set query string
http-request set-query lead 

# redirect -  this is actually a pretty tricky way to redirect
# to the modified request without giving path
http-request redirect scheme http code 301

# empty prefix could be use as well
# http-request redirect prefix ' ' code 301
```

In versions older than 1.6, you may use [`reqrep`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#reqrep) to mimic similar functionality. For example:

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /rty/(.*)     \1\ /\2
redirect scheme http code 301
```

Note: I've skipped the acl part as an exercise (but it looks ok).